# Can't decompress csv: "No space left on device", but using EC2 m3.2xlarge?

Tags: amazon-ec2, gzip, diskspace

I'm attempting to decompress a csv file on my EC2 instance. The instance should definitely be large enough so I guess it has to do with partitioning, but I am new to that stuff and don't really understand the posts I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561578/getting-no-space-left-on-device-for-approx-10-gb-of-data-on-emr-m1-large-inst) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706398/ubuntu-no-space-left-on-device-but-there-is-tons-of-space), or whether they apply to me. (I'm not using Hadoop nor do I have a full "/tmp" folder). The .csv.gz file is 1.6 GB and it should be 14 GB decompressed. Executing `gzip -d data.csv.gz`, I get the error `gzip: data.csv: No space left on device`, and `df -h` shows:

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  2.8G  5.0G  36% /
devtmpfs         15G   56K   15G   1% /dev
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your root drive (/dev/xvda1) has 5GB free space. try running it within `/dev/shm`

Comment: Yeah, alright. I wasn't sure what 'tmpfs' was so didn't want to mess with it. I didn't realize that the storage you got assigned with larger instances wouldn't be in your root directory and worse as far as I can tell wouldn't be anywhere in your directory structure at all. I realized you have to go make & attach volumes, and then mount them. (correct me if there's another way) I'm still learning about it but I will leave this comment up for other clueless beginners.